# how to conditionally assign classes in jsx with mixed tailwind and normal classes

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, jsx, tailwind-css

Why in **Nextjs 14 (ReactJS 18)** , within a `jsx` code if I assign `css` classes conditionally like so:

```
 <Swiper
  className={lightbox ? 
"swiperLightbox h-[80%] md:h-[70vh] z-50" :
 "swiperMain h-[21vmax] rounded-xl"} 
 >
```

when `lightbox` condition is `true` the element has both classes `swiperMain` and `swiperLightbox` but has been correctly assigned other Tailwind classes accordingly?

Also when `lightbox` is `false` it only has `swiperMain` and Tailwind classes correctly.

Comment: The above is how you correctly assign condition classnames, there must be something else causing the issue you're experiencing. Mind adding your Tailwind config above to help up get the full picture?

Answer (score -1):

```
<Swiper className={[
     "swiperMain h-[21vmax] rounded-xl",
     lightbox ? "swiperLightbox h-[80%] md:h-[70vh] z-50" : "",
   ].join(" ")}>
 </Swiper>
```

i hope this will solve your problem

Thanks